# Why does floating div make the next div take up whole space?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I know that float takes element out of normal flow partially. What came to my surprise was that I observed the next div of a floating div taking the space of floating div too. Example:

```css
.header {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.footer {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER is yellow with red border</div>
</div>
```

Here the yellow footer comes after the green header, but the way it behaves is as if it were the container of header. The border is drawn out of both header and footer. In principle, footer should draw border only around itself. What is the reason for this behavior?

Another surprise is the green color(background) opaques the yellow one. Is this how stacking order works? Is it normal that div later in html order comes below the former divs in stacking order?

Please give reference to explain the behaviors.

Comment: It only looks like the header is contained in the footer because you floated the header. Remove the unnecessary properties in your example like width, height, padding and put some content between the two divs and you'll see that the footer moves down the page and the header isn't contained in it.

Comment: @j08691 In that case, the content I'll put will act like container of header. I think its how float works; For non-floating elements the content of floating div is present but not the floating div itself.

Comment: Also, I think `clear` property on `footer` pushes it down because, may be, it makes the footer think that preceding floating div is now in-flow.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour occurs because as you said floated elements are taken out of flow and so the element next to them rise up and take their space. But floated elements are taken out of flow only partially. Partially, in the sense that elements next to them ignore them like they are not in flow anymore, but the content within them still respects these floated elements and hence is pushed horizontally or vertically.

You can think of floated elements like floating above other elements. Also, the content of other elements is also sort of risen above them. So, their plane (or background-color) goes below floated elements, but the content is pushed downwards  (or horizontally).

Regarding your particular case, you should remember that element next to floated element always takes up the space of the floated element. In your demo, it seems slightly confusing because your floated element has width set to 100% which causes the next element's content to push downwards not only horizontally. Hope that makes sense?

### Analogy

As an analogy, you can think of all html elements as 1cm thick wooden boards, with some thick alphabet blocks placed above them. Somewhat like this image below:

[image]

Now suppose you have two such elements, first is header with alphabets HEADER and below that footer with alphabets FOOTER.

When you apply `float: left` to header element, it rises 1cm above the surface and floats towards left boundary of the page. Now, that it's not level with its next element, its next element rises up and towards left as far as it can. But as the floated element has risen only 1cm above, only the bottom wooden board of next element goes up, while all the alphabets get pushed down by the floated element.